# Wordpress. Вывод metabox полей для заполнения гостями на сайте

Tags: php, wordpress

Пытаюсь реализовать функцию создания постов гостями, чтобы они сами не регистрируясь могли создать пост на сайте, а после подтверждения через админку пост публиковался. Удалось найти несколько подходящих плагинов, но проблема в том, что в админке для написания постов я использую метабоксы. В последующем эти поля используются для сортировки на сайте. Собственно вопрос, а можно ли реализовать вывод metabox полей для заполнения гостями?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> а можно ли реализовать вывод metabox полей для заполнения гостями?

Можно, если понимать что "метабокс"- всего лишь html-оформление блока и ничего не говорит о его содержимом/данных. И вообще, грубо говоря, метабокс - это в админке, а на фронте это виджет или иное представление для вывода или получения неких данных. (вангую - ты толкуешь о [произвольных полях](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F), но ничего ж об этом не говоришь)

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/

**АПД**.
Нашел в закромах ;):

> Метабокс (Metabox) – это обособленный участок **HTML-формы**, показываемый
>   на страницах добавления или редактирования постов. Метабокс
>   предназначен для указания каких-то параметров и свойств поста, которые
>   вместе с другими данными сохраняются в БД.
>
> Метабоксы бывают трёх видов:
>
> - Стандартный метабокс (Built-in Metabox)
>     К ним относятся такие как 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments',
>     'revisions', 'page-attributes' и 'post-formats'. Для настраиваемых
>     типов постов названия стандартных метабоксов, которые должны
>     отображаться на страницах добавления или редактирования этих
>     нестандартных постов, указываются в параметрах функции
>     register_post_type() или с помощью функции add_post_type_support().
> - Метабоксы для таксономии (Taxonomy Metabox)
>     Данные метабоксы предназначены для того, чтобы посты можно было ассоциировать с тем или иным термом таксономии. Метабоксы для
>     таксономии автоматически появляются на страницах добавления или
>     редактирования постов, если для данного типа постов зарегистрировать
>     какую-нибудь таксономию с помощью функций register_post_type(),
>     register_taxonomy() или register_taxonomy_for_object_type(). При
>     добавлении обычных постов Вордпресса можно видеть два дефолтных
>     метабокса таксономий: «Рубрики» («Categories») и «Метки» («Post
>     Tags»).
> - Настраиваемые метабоксы (Custom Metabox)
>     Такие метабоксы предназначены для самых разнообразных целей, изначально не предусмотренных разработчиками Вордпресса, и они
>     добавляются на страницы добавления или редактирования постов с помощью
>     функции add_meta_box() разработчиками тем Вордпресса. Данные,
>     добавляемые из Настраиваемых Метабоксов, удобно сохранять в
>     Произвольных Полях для поста.